# App not uploading on PlayStore

Tags: android, google-play

Its been almost 2 days since I published my app on play store. The package name is com.codebrew.bmp3

The app was published properly and play store said it will be available soon in store(I uploaded many apps earlier and everytime this message comes as Google takes time to analyze the app). But this time, its has been very long. I can't even found the app using the url i.e. 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.codebrew.bmp3

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

EDIT: After uploading this app, I uploaded one more app and it is available on store.

Comment: What does the Google Play Developer Console now tell you? Are users getting errors as they try installing your app? Is your app published anywhere (even if it's not visible to you in your country)?

Comment: @StephanBranczyk The app is not visible in play store. And the console  is showing: "No data for this application"

Comment: Do you really hit the Publish button ? Or after uploading APK how many supported devices ?

Comment: @Steve Yes ofcourse I hit publish button. And the min version of app is 9 and max version is 17. And I am looking for app on my laptop in the browser.

Comment: Okey! this seems an exceptional case to me or you are violating Google content policy. Contact Google Play support for the same.

Answer (score 0):

where did you upload it? production? beta? or alpha? if beta and alpha you can't see it on the Play store website because it's only available for tester.

Comment: Production. Sorry for late reply.

Comment: Maybe there's some case that you need to contact Google as Steve said